# How to run a regression with a categorical DV and both categorical and continuous IV's (in R)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a data set with a categorical dependent (14 categories - party choices), and three independent variables - age (continuous), education (8 categories) and gender (male or female).

Online I understood that I need to run a multiple regression analysis. However, advice online is conflicting, with some proposing the use of dummies while others do not.

Could you please help me with some guidance? The software I work in is RStudio.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vlad

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 3):

I'm worried that this question is a duplicate, but I'll answer it anyway. What you are describing can be called "supervised classification". There are a wide range of tools that you can use to solve such a problem, and each tool has its own strengths and weaknesses. Here is a brief summary of your options, [borrowed shamelessly](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/)

- Multinomial logistic regression: the crux of what is discussed [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/)
- Multinomial probit regression: similar to multinomial logistic regression with independent normal error terms. [This](https://imai.princeton.edu/research/files/MNPjss.pdf) is a nice R package for that.
- Multiple-group discriminant analysis: My personal favorite, but it does have some limitations (assuming multivariate normality of the errors for one). See [this post](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/qda-several-groups) on how to perform it in R.

The article lists a few other options for you to explore. Beyond their options, Random Forests via [Classification Trees](http://www.bios.unc.edu/~dzeng/BIOS740/randomforest.pdf) is also very powerful, but can be too "black box" for some people.